# (Oracle) How to extract a specialized UDO from a object table based on a generalized UDO?

Tags: oracle, struct, user-defined-types

I apologize in advance for not knowing the terminology, but here it goes:

How do I extract a specialized UDO (UDO= user defined object & specialized= that 'extends' or is 'under' another UDO) that I inserted in a object table defined for a generalized UDO (generalized - higher in the same UDO hierarchy).

Details:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE GENERIC_UDO AS OBJECT (
    atribute_1 TYPE,
    ...
    atribute_n TYPE2, //TYPE2 is a nested table
) NOT FINAL NOT INSTANTIABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SPECIALIZED_UDO UNDER GENERIC_UDO (
    atribute_1 TYPE,
    ...
    atribute_q TYPE3, //TYPE3 is also a nested table
) FINAL INSTANTIABLE;

CREATE TABLE TBL_GENERIC_UDO OF GENERIC_UDO 
(  CONSTRAINT PK...)
... //other nested tables
NESTED TABLE atribute_n STORE AS atribute_n_nst;
```

So this works: 
`INSERT INTO TBL_GENERIC_UDO values (new TBL_GENERIC_UDO(...));` because TBL_GENERIC_UDO is 'under' GENERIC_UDO.
A `'select * from TBL_GENERIC_UDO'` shows me as columns just the GENERIC_UDO atributes (as expected!)

So how do I extract or extract and convert, because I need to read back the inserted SPECIALIZED_UDO.

I payed a bit with:

- VALUE(x): `SELECT VALUE(tgo) FROM TBL_GENERIC_UDO tgo;`
- TREAT(x as Y): `SELECT TREAT(VALUE(tgo) as SPECIALIZED_UDO) FROM TBL_GENERIC_UDO tgo;`

and no good results. Actually in booth cases I get

---

- `SCHEMANAME.SPECIALIZED_UDO(values, values,..., null)`
- `oracle.sql.STRUCT@54faa2`

In the first case, when I did the insert, the corespondent value for atribute_q was set to null, in the second one it was a proper value, ex: `SPECIALIZED_UDO('value1','value1',...)`

I am asumming thats because TBL_GENERIC_UDO doesnt have a store clause for atribute_q from SPECIALIZED_UDO.

So anyone thoughts, explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: Oracle's SQL type implemenation is not widely understood (or used).  So you need to make your question *really clear*.  It would help us to understand if you posted a working test case - with data - which demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself! Wasn't that hardcore as I expected. First I thought that Oracle will 'truncate' when inserting a specialized UDO into the table defined for a generic UDO, and in my case the specialized UDO had additionally another nested table as a atribute, but it doesn't.

Check code example, last line is the most important one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_TBL_TEXT IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_CONTAINER1 AS OBJECT (
    ATRIBUTE NUMBER(6),
    TBL_TEXT OBJ_TBL_TEXT
) NOT FINAL NOT INSTANTIABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_CONTAINER2 UNDER OBJ_CONTAINER1(
    SECOND_TBL_TEXT OBJ_TBL_TEXT
) FINAL INSTANTIABLE;

CREATE TABLE TBL_CONTAINER1 OF OBJ_CONTAINER1 
(  CONSTRAINT PK_TBL_CONTAINER1 PRIMARY KEY(ATRIBUTE))
NESTED TABLE TBL_TEXT STORE AS TBL_TEXT_NST;

INSERT INTO TBL_CONTAINER1 VALUES (NEW OBJ_CONTAINER2(1,null,null));
INSERT INTO TBL_CONTAINER1 VALUES (NEW OBJ_CONTAINER2(2,null, OBJ_TBL_TEXT('VAL1','VAL2')));
INSERT INTO TBL_CONTAINER1 VALUES (NEW OBJ_CONTAINER2(3,OBJ_TBL_TEXT('VAL3','VAL4'), null));
INSERT INTO TBL_CONTAINER1 VALUES (NEW OBJ_CONTAINER2(4,OBJ_TBL_TEXT('VAL5','VAL6'), OBJ_TBL_TEXT('VAL7','VAL8')));
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT * FROM TBL_CONTAINER1;
SELECT VALUE(tc) FROM TBL_CONTAINER1 tc;
SELECT TREAT(VALUE(tc) as OBJ_CONTAINER2).SECOND_TBL_TEXT FROM TBL_CONTAINER1 tc;
```

**First select** will display as columns just the atributes from the OBJ_CONTAINER1, like:

```
ATTRIBUTE| TBL_TEXT
--===============--
- 1   (null)
- 2   (null)
- 3   VARCHAR(VAL3,VAL4)
- 4   VARCHAR(VAL5,VAL6)
```

**Second** one looks weirder

```
VALUE(TC)
--=====--
DATAMODELER.OBJ_CONTAINER2(1,null,null)
oracle.sql.STRUCT@57ac8e
oracle.sql.STRUCT@1df6f
oracle.sql.STRUCT@f40801
```

VALUE - returns the object instance for a row of an object table as associated with the correlation_variable (table alias)

**Third** one lets me have access to nested attributes not mention in the nested clause in the creation of TBL_CONTAINER1.

```
TREAT(VALUE(tc) as OBJ_CONTAINER2).SECOND_TBL_TEXT
--==============================================--
(null)
VARCHAR(VAL1,VAL2)
(null)
VARCHAR(VAL7,VAL8)
```

It is exactly what I needed. Dont know yet how Oracle stores the additional attributes, and don't care. Though to share the solution...